# Is there a way to inherit from a (preferably abstract) base razor class?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

What I presently have is:

```
@page "/Manager/ListCampaigns"

<OrganizationFilter ValuesChanged="@OnListChanged"
                    SearchAsync="@SearchCampaigns">
</OrganizationFilter>

<OrganizationGrid @bind-Data="@Values"
                  UrlFileName="Campaign">
</OrganizationGrid>
```

OrganizationFilter.razor:

```
<DxFormLayout>
    <DxFormLayoutGroup Caption="Filter (search)" ColSpanMd="10">
        <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Name:" ColSpanMd="4">
            <DxTextBox @bind-Text="@SearchName"></DxTextBox>
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
        <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Unique Id:" ColSpanMd="4">
            <DxTextBox @bind-Text="@SearchUniqueId"></DxTextBox>
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
        <DxFormLayoutItem ColSpanMd="2">
            <DxButton Text="Search" Click="@SearchOrganizations"></DxButton>
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
    </DxFormLayoutGroup>
</DxFormLayout>
```

OrganizationGrid.razor:

```
<DxGrid @bind-Data="@Data"
        PageSize="5"
        CssClass="dx-datagrid"
        PagerNavigationMode="PagerNavigationMode.InputBox"
        PageSizeSelectorVisible="true"
        PageSizeSelectorAllRowsItemVisible="true"
        PageSizeSelectorItems="@(new[] { 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 })">
    <Columns>
        <DxGridDataColumn >
            <HeaderCaptionTemplate>
                @{
                    var urlCreate = $"/Manager/{@UrlFileName}?mode=create&returnUrl={@ReturnUrl}";
                }
                <NavLink href="@urlCreate">create</NavLink>
            </HeaderCaptionTemplate>
            <CellDisplayTemplate>
                @context.DisplayText &nbsp;
                @{
                    var dataItem = context.DataItem as IOrganization;
                    var uniqueId = dataItem?.UniqueId;
                    var urlView = $"/Manager/{@UrlFileName}?mode=read&uniqueId={@uniqueId}&returnUrl={@ReturnUrl}";
                    var urlEdit = $"/Manager/{@UrlFileName}?mode=update&uniqueId={@uniqueId}&returnUrl={@ReturnUrl}";
                }
                <NavLink class="btn btn-link" href="@urlView">view</NavLink>
                &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                <NavLink class="btn btn-link" href="@urlEdit">edit</NavLink>
            </CellDisplayTemplate>
        </DxGridDataColumn>
        <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Name" FieldName="Name" />
        <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Unique Id" FieldName="UniqueId" />
        <DxGridDataColumn Caption="Region" FieldName="Parent.Name" />
    </Columns>
</DxGrid>
```

If this was just C# classes, this would be a piece of cake to write the 2nd and 3rd razor files in a base class and then the top razor would extend that class. Very clean and neat. Any way to do this with razor files?

I assume not (I can think of several reasons why this would be very difficult and if possible, problematic), but it never hurts to ask.

Comment: So what does an inheriting class to `ListCampaigns` look like.  What Ui do you want it to inherit.  There are ways.  The principal problem is that `ComponentBase` wasn't designed to be a wrapper so you have to do some hoop jumping to achieve what you want [or use a different base class].

Comment: PS [being pedantic] - `<OrganizationGrid @bind-Data="@Values"
                  UrlFileName="Campaign" />` is a more concise and clearer way to declare components that have no child content.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Basically I'd like to put the contents of `OrganizationFilter ' and `OrganizationGrid' in a 'ListOrganizations` razor. And then create `ListCampaigns`, 'ListStates`, etc. that all inherit from it where it then makes the changes needed for each of the super classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to inherit from a (preferably abstract) base razor class? .... I assume not....

You are constrained by the `ComponentBase` cage, not Blazor.

Step outside that cage and yes you can.  You can read more here, with example alternative components - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5345758/Building-Leaner-Meaner-Greener-Blazor-Components

`ComponentBase` may be a Swiss army knife, jack of all trades, master of none component implementation, but it can't do everything.  A template component being a good example.

If you stay in the cage then you can put the block in a render fragment in the base component:

```cs
protected RenderFragment CommonStuff => (__builder) => {
   <OrganizationFilter ValuesChanged="@OnListChanged"
                    SearchAsync="@SearchCampaigns" />
   <OrganizationGrid @bind-Data="@Values"
                  UrlFileName="Campaign" />
};
```

And then add:

```cs
@CommonStuff
```

Wherever you need it.  Not nice.

### An alternative using a new base component

`BlazrComponent` [shown at  the end if this answer] is a "black box" replacement for `ComponentBase` that also includes templating.

You can use it like this.

The base template containing your template code.  `this.Content` is a `RenderFragment` that will contain the child content.

```
// MyTemplate.razor
@inherits BlazrComponent

@*No Content Here - It won't get rendered*@

@code {
    protected override RenderFragment Template => (__builder) =>
    {
        <div class="bg-danger m-3 p-3">@this.Content</div>
    };
}
```

And then inherit your actual page component from the template:

```
@page "/counter"
@inherits MyTemplate

//....
```

BlazrComponent

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;
namespace Blazr.UI;

public class BlazrComponent : IComponent, IHandleEvent, IHandleAfterRender
{
    private Guid Uid = Guid.NewGuid();
    private RenderHandle _renderHandle;
    private RenderFragment _componentContent;
    private bool _renderPending;
    private bool _hasNotInitialized = true;
    private bool _hasNeverRendered = true;
    private bool _hasCalledOnAfterRender;

    public BlazrComponent()
    {
        this.Content = this.BuildRenderTree;
        _componentContent = (builder) =>
        {
            _renderPending = false;
            _hasNeverRendered = false;

            if (this.Template is null)
                this.Content.Invoke(builder);
            else
                this.Template.Invoke(builder);
        };
    }

    public void Attach(RenderHandle renderHandle)
        => _renderHandle = renderHandle;

    public virtual async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        await this.ParametersSetAsync();
    }

    protected async Task ParametersSetAsync()
    {
        Task? initTask = null;
        var hasRenderedOnYield = false;

        // If this is the initial call then we need to run the OnInitialized methods
        if (_hasNotInitialized)
        {
            this.OnInitialized();
            initTask = this.OnInitializedAsync();
            hasRenderedOnYield = await this.CheckIfShouldRunStateHasChanged(initTask);
            _hasNotInitialized = false;
        }

        this.OnParametersSet();
        var task = this.OnParametersSetAsync();

        // check if we need to do the render on Yield i.e.
        //  - this is not the initial run or
        //  - OnInitializedAsync did not yield
        var shouldRenderOnYield = initTask is null || !hasRenderedOnYield;

        if (shouldRenderOnYield)
            await this.CheckIfShouldRunStateHasChanged(task);
        else
            await task;

        // run the final state has changed to update the UI.
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected virtual void OnInitialized() { }

    protected virtual Task OnInitializedAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;

    protected virtual void OnParametersSet() { }

    protected virtual Task OnParametersSetAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;

    protected virtual void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender) { }

    protected virtual Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) => Task.CompletedTask;

    protected virtual void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder) { }

    protected virtual bool ShouldRender() => true;

    protected virtual RenderFragment? Template { get; }

    protected RenderFragment Content { get; } 
    
    public void StateHasChanged()
    {
        if (_renderPending)
            return;

        var shouldRender = _hasNeverRendered || ShouldRender() || _renderHandle.IsRenderingOnMetadataUpdate;

        if (shouldRender)
        {
            _renderPending = true;
            _renderHandle.Render(_componentContent);
        }
    }

    async Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem item, object? obj)
    {
        var uiTask = item.InvokeAsync(obj);

        await this.CheckIfShouldRunStateHasChanged(uiTask);

        this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    Task IHandleAfterRender.OnAfterRenderAsync()
    {
        var firstRender = !_hasCalledOnAfterRender;
        _hasCalledOnAfterRender = true;

        OnAfterRender(firstRender);

        return OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    protected async Task<bool> CheckIfShouldRunStateHasChanged(Task task)
    {
        var isCompleted = task.IsCompleted || task.IsCanceled;

        if (!isCompleted)
        {
            this.StateHasChanged();
            await task;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected Task InvokeAsync(Action workItem)
        => _renderHandle.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(workItem);

    protected Task InvokeAsync(Func<Task> workItem)
        => _renderHandle.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(workItem);
}
```